# Using Reserved words as fields name

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am using external WSDL class for creating apex classes for my project, some of the classes have fields which name is reserved in apex, as `limit` word.
My problem here is, i can't call that field, sample example:

```
System.debug(object.limit);
```

where limit is field in object.
I can't even save the file because there is error in console saying:

```
Variable does not exist: limit
```

Any idea how reserved word in this cases can be escaped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made an alternative version of Wsdl2Apex. You can get it for free from the [FuseIT website](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer).

In this alternative version it will add a `_x` suffix to the generated apex code for any reserved keywords that are encountered. The underlying generated SOAP request won't have this suffix.

Comment: I will use it! If I have any trouble I will notice you. Thanks.